# Is there a way to add personal text on mouseOver to fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar, mouseover

I'm trying to add personal text to mouseover inside fullcalendar. The script below works only for the title of the event.
Example: [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/G6K6Y/358/).
Please how can I make the mouseover show my personal text.

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,

    // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
            $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
        }
    },

    // For DEMO only
    // *************
    events: [
        {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
        allDay: false},
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ]
});

});​
```

Comment: What do you mean? On every cell to show a title, or to show a title on whole calendar ?

Comment: What personal text? And on which mouseover?

Comment: @henrik I want to add some personal text to each event so that as the user mouse over cells that has an event, the additional text that is included will be shown. Only cells that has events will carry the additional text .

Thanks

Comment: So something like `title: 'Birthday Party', text: 'Please bring a gift to the birthday boy!'` where the text parameter should show aswell as the title?

Comment: @Henrik Yes.. But the extra text has to be a mouseover, while the actual name of the event remain as it is.

Comment: Thats quite an extensive edit of the `fullCalendar.js` since it includes adding another attribute and using it to create a new layer that pops out with the extra information.

Comment: @HenrikAmmer - FullCalendar supports custom attributes in the event object. Oyesanmi - please check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12266412/1183042) below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using the `eventRender` callback.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/h9cC6/

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var additionaltext="this is aditional text";

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,

    // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
            $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
        }
    },

    // For DEMO only
    // *************
    events: [
        {
        title: 'All Day Event' + additionaltext,
        start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
    {
        title: 'Long Event' + additionaltext,
        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event' + additionaltext,
        start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
        allDay: false},
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event' + additionaltext,
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Meeting' + additionaltext,
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Lunch' + additionaltext,
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
        allDay: false},
    {
        title: 'Click for Google' + additionaltext,
        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
        url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ]
});

});​
```

look for it are you waiting for same if yes mark as an answer